# How can I structure this Rails/PostgreSQL query to return instances of a model based on an attribute on the model's children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm working on an app where a `User` has many projects and a `Project` has many roles. `Role` has a boolean `filled` attribute to indicate when someone has taken the role on.

I'd like to build a query which returns all projects that either have **no roles** or have **roles which have all been filled**. This is the closest I've got so far:

```
@user.projects.includes(:roles).where("roles.id IS NULL OR roles.filled IS TRUE").references(:roles)
```

The problem is that the `roles.filled IS TRUE` part of the query is matching projects with a mixture of filled and unfilled roles. I need this to only match projects on which *all* roles are filled.

Searching the PostgreSQL documentation, it looks like [`bool_and`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) is probably the way to go but my SQL skills aren't great and I haven't managed to get it working yet.

I realise I could do this easily with `select` or `reject` but I'd like to keep it efficient by just querying the database.

Can anyone offer some advice please?

Update: The (simplified) models and their relationships:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

**app/models/project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :roles
end
```

**app/models/role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  # `filled` is a boolean attribute with a default value of false
end
```

Comment: So, your condition is that the projects should have all roles filled in or none? Can you show how you models are relating to each other?

Comment: @lcguida I've added the models to the question :)

Comment: I answered but to be accurate I must know if you require that all roles.id are null or any roles.id is null

Comment: @charlysisto Thanks Charles, the `roles.id IS NULL` part of my query is just supposed to return projects which have no roles. This is in addition to projects for which all roles are filled.

Comment: Ah yes of course : see my updated content :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must resort to an [aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) since the condition applies to the combination of many records (all fields of `roles.filled` must be true). So you group all roles by `projects.id` and check if `every(roles.filled)` is true:

Here's a proposal :

```
@user.projects.
      joins("left outer join roles on roles.project_id = projects.id").
      group("projects.id").
      having("every(roles.filled IS TRUE) OR every(roles.id IS NULL)")
      select("projects.*")
```

**Update** : Ok here's the logic behind this SQL :

> for every project, I'll check if it has NO roles.id OR ONLY roles.filled. The reason you cannot use the where clause for `roles.id IS TRUE`is that it would only select those, before grouping and filtering in the `having` clause and therefore excluding the `roles.filled`rows. In other words it would be the equivalent of doing `roles.id is NULL AND Roles.filled IS TRUE`

Comment: This looks good to me but it's raising a `PG::UndefinedTable` error:
```: SELECT projects.* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY roles.project_id HAVING bool_and(roles.filled IS TRUE) OR bool_or(roles.id IS NULL)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "roles"
LINE 1: ...d" = $1 GROUP BY roles.project_id HAVING bool_and(roles.fill...```

Comment: Sorry, formatting in comments mangled that a bit. Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/sstarr/85caa3f5973c004548ee

Comment: oh weird.... try with eager_load instead of includes (as corrected in the answer)

Comment: This certainly looks to me like it should work but now I'm getting a `PG::GroupingError` instead: https://gist.github.com/sstarr/85caa3f5973c004548ee

Comment: Another grouping error, this time for `roles.id` which doesn't make sense to me since we don't want to group by roles.id and it looks like it is being used in an aggregate function: https://gist.github.com/sstarr/85caa3f5973c004548ee

Comment: It looks like `eager_load` is overriding the select clause (and putting an unwanted roles.id in it...!) you should probably replace `eager_load` with a custom joins (with outer join) : `joins("left outer join roles on roles.project_id = projects.id") ` Tell me if this works

Comment: That did it! Thank you for your patience :)